# Does Domain and Hosting Transfer affect search engine ranking?

Tags: seo, web-hosting, transfer

Im planning to transfer my domain from my current provider since there have been problems with hosting,webmail and poor support.

Will transferring the domain and changing the host affect my search engine ranking and SEO in anyway?

Answer (score 1):

If the new hosting plan and server configuration is not optimal for your specific requirements then it is possible that you may experience some negative repercussions of switching.

Your new hosting provider and/or web developer / IT dept. should be able to assist in making sure the switch over to new hosting / server(s) is as smooth as possible.

It is best to leave your hosting plan intact and up and running for a good month after you have switched hosting just in case any DNS is resolving to the  IP address of the server instead of / as well as the domain name(s). This way, you have a full month of DNS resolving to old server and new server before you terminate the old.

Comment: Thanks will do that but My question is about search engine ranking?

Comment: That is what I answered... You can learn more though at the question that this one has been marked a duplicate of above.